# Eclipse bug? Java/Groovy visibility of private fields

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I have two classes, an abstract Java class, and a Groovy subclass extending the Java class. They look something like this:

(Java)

```
public abstract class Testing1 {
    private static int myField = 0; //static not relevant to the issue.
}
```

(Groovy)

```
class Testing2 extends Testing1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        println myField;
    }
}
```

Now, as the field is declared private running `Testing2` gives an exception. As expected. However, Eclipse doesn't give any warnings saying that this field is not visible, and even auto-completes the `myField` word should you type it! Is there an Eclipse setting I can activate so that I don't burn myself when coding Java and Groovy?

Comment: does it happen if the field is not static too?

Comment: @blackdrag Yes, it does happen (but only if the method in `Testing2` is not static as well.)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an greclipse bug to me, since there should be no such option. Groovy does not provide private access for sub classes to parent classes. The static case is a bit arguable, since Testing1.myField is technically allowed in Groovy. But since you confirmed that this happens for instance fields as well, I am pretty sure, that this is unintended behavior

Filling a bug report here: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE would help a lot